# How to change color of bar graph by mouse click event in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart, mouseclick-event

I want to create a bar graph in which, after a mouse click event, the colors of the bar change according to the color bar. The selected value is displayed with a horizontal threshold line and the bars are supposed to change color depending on the probability of the selected value being above or below the mean of the sample.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to connect the mouse click event and the color bar values to the bar graph values and produce the desired result.(color bar depicts probability)
I am new to this and any feedback would be appreciated.

```
df = df1.T
mean = list(df.mean().values)
std = list(df.std().values)
x = range(1,len(mean)+1)
sqrt = len(df.iloc[:,0:1])**0.5
CI = []
for i in range(len(std)):
    CI.append((1.96*std[i])/sqrt)

years = [1992,1993,1994,1995]
prob = np.arange(0,1.1,0.1)
start_line_value = 5000

norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(30e3, 60e3)
plt.xticks([i for i in range(1,len(years)+1)],years)
color_map = plt.cm.get_cmap('seismic_r')
colors = color_map(mean)
CS = plt.contourf([x,mean],prob,cmap=color_map)
cbar = plt.colorbar(CS, cmap=color_map)
cbar.set_label('Probability', rotation=0,labelpad=25)
bars = plt.bar(x,mean,width = 1,color = plt.cm.seismic_r(norm(mean)),yerr = CI ,align = 'center',capsize = 10,alpha = 0.99)
ax = plt.axes()

class AfterClicking(object):
    
    def __init__(self,ax):
        
        self.fig = ax.figure
        self.ax = ax
        self.start_line = ax.axhline(y = start_line_value,linewidth = 1,color = 'black')
        trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)
        self.value = ax.text(0,start_line_value, "{:.0f}".format(start_line_value), color="blue", transform=trans,ha="right", va="center")
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.draw_line_on_click)
        ax.set_title('Marker at {} on Y axis'.format(start_line_value))
        
    def draw_line_on_click(self,event):
        
        self.start_line.remove()
        self.value.remove()
        self.start_line = plt.axhline(y = event.ydata ,linewidth = 1,color = 'black')
        trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)
        self.value = ax.text(0,event.ydata, "{:.0f}".format(event.ydata), color="blue", transform=trans,ha="right", va="center")
        ax.set_title('Marker at {} on Y axis'.format(event.ydata))
        
    
answer = AfterClicking(ax)
```